# Geoserver Importer Plugin Error "java.io.IOException: Schema 'x' does not exist" - Ubuntu

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, import, ubuntu, geoserver-importer

I am new to GeoServer and wanted to import several shapefiles with one command.
Therefore I installed the GeoServer importer extension to get this task done.

I selected the import directory, the workspace and the preferred store:

[image]

The next step would be to Import all the selected .shp files at once but I get the following error:

[image]

I am not using SQL or PostGIS.

Comment: are all the parts of the shapefiles present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was that I used german "ä ü ö" characters inside the features of the uploaded shapefiles. I had to reinstall geoserver.